# Routing and packet mangling

Tags: iptables, routing

I’m looking to get packets from one subnet to another more than one hop away; take for example:

[ 192.168.0.4 ] - - - > [ 192.168.10.11 ] - - - > [ 172.23.100.13 ]

I would like 192.168.0.4 to connect to 172.23.100.13, but the problem is:

```
# ip route add 172.23.100.13/32 via 192.168.10.11
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

As I understand, `Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.` means, “you can’t do that because 192.168.10.11 is not on the 192.168.0.0/24 network, which is the network you’re on.”

My question is whether this is possible with iptables rules; I presume it is possible, but I have not been able to get things working just yet.  After some reading, I tried to set a PREROUTING nat rule to send packets going to 172.23.100.13 over to 192.168.10.11:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.23.100.13 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.11
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.  I’m not even sure how to go about debugging.  I have tried:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.23.100.13 -j LOG
```

but nothing appears in the logs

I have also tried tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -i <interface> -vv | egrep '(172.23.109.13|192.168.10.11)’ &
```

but only get the following repeating line:

```
192.168.0.4.43898 > 172.23.100.13.8000: Flags [S], cksum 0x2374 (incorrect -> 0xa00f), seq 573960788, win 62727, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 1537225626 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Is this the correct approach?  Any clues on what to check for?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just have a gateway on the subnet?  That's the traditional way of getting packets from one subnet to another.  How do you expect 192.168.0.4 to send traffic to 192.168.10.11 when it's not on the same subnet in the first place without a router?

Comment: My expectation is clouded with misunderstanding.  ;)  For starters, I should clarify that these are two subnets on AWS.  Machine `192.168.0.4` can send traffic to `192.168.10.11`; there is a router between the two machines, but it's opaque and handled by AWS, not me.  Conceptually -- again based on misunderstanding -- I'd assume since these two machines can already talk to each other, I can somehow add a route saying, "this packet goes to `172.23.100.13`, and in order to get there, send it to `192.168.10.11` first."  But, fundamentally, that's not how routing works, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the missing piece to this puzzle.  Machine `192.168.10.11` is able to send packets to `172.23.100.13` because there is, what appears to be, a VXLAN interface for the `172.23.100.0/24` network; hence back to the fundamental requirement that two networks have to be connected on a machine in order to route to them.